# FrameLayout : bring one layout ontop of another layout programatically

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a frame layout that consists of two child linear layouts( one on top of another)
 I have two buttons "1" and "2"
When i press 1 i want the first linear layout on top of second linear layout

When i press 2 i want the second linear layout on top of first linear layout

I used bringToFront()  to do so
But nothing happens

**my layout**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#D88681"
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#57E8A7"
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**my main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

LinearLayout first, second;
Button btn1, btn2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    first = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.firstLayout);
    second = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondLayout);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                first.bringToFront();
            }


    });


    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                second.bringToFront();
            }
    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bringtofront() method to set the visibility of the Linearlayouts.
for example.

```
     first.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

this will make the first view dissapear and the second view visible.

Comment: But the child views will also dissappear if the parent layout is set invisible. I dont want this to happen

Comment: ok. i dont really understand why you need one underneatheath the other then. why not have them all in the same layout

Comment: i want the overlay effect on button press ,, so placing them on single layout would not give me that

Comment: you want to animate an effect. this wasnt explained in the oiginal question

Comment: by overlay effect i meant one on top of another ,,,sry for confusing

Comment: bro found out the answer ,,,i forgot to invalidate the parent layout,, added the answer have a look,, and thanks for trying to help

Comment: overlay effect. not sure what that is. you could animate the colours to with a transition drawable and add clicklisteners after the animation is completed. im not sure overlaying linearlayouts is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to invalidate the parent layout
Add this

```
myView.bringToFront();
    ((View)myView.getParent()).invalidate();
                ((View)myView.getParent()).requestLayout();
```